# illegal instruction (object_recognition)

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I'm fairly new to ROS and I'm starting by trying to play with the object recognition packages in electric. I can run:

$rosrun object_recognition_core orb_template.py -o my_textured_plane

with no problems. It makes five .yaml files in a directory called my_textured_plane.
Note: it does not create an image named "train.png" in that same directory. It saves the image in the directory above as "image_0000.png".
When I run :

$rosrun object_recognition_core orb_track.py --track_directory my_textured_plane

I get an illegal instruction error. More details below - I did gdb python and ran the orb_track.py file:

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/python /opt/ros/electric/stacks/object_recognition/object_recognition_core/bin/orb_track.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Registration? 1
Sync? 0
[New Thread 0x7fffe3f9d700 (LWP 448)]
[Thread 0x7fffe3f9d700 (LWP 448) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffe3f9d700 (LWP 450)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe379c700 (LWP 452)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe0ea5700 (LWP 454)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdf024700 (LWP 455)]
[New Thread 0x7fffde823700 (LWP 456)]
[New Thread 0x7fffde022700 (LWP 457)]
1. device on bus: 1 @ 18 with serial number: B00363276005047B  Microsoft : Xbox NUI Camera
Time diff max: 33.5333
Registered:on Supported: 1
Setting registration on
Setting sync off
Reading : ./T.yaml
Reading : ./R.yaml
Reading : ./descriptors.yaml
Reading : ./points3d.yaml
Reading : ./points.yaml
read image:./train.png
width:0 height:0 channels:1

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.

0x00007fffe6904449 in operator() (

    b=0x2e1af40 "\001\355\250\036\233\324e\367\377\\\224\276\001\237\246\250\201\320RDζP\372tY\250|\032\n\303A\367\354~\346W\275}\016\244M\377\277\377\277\063\314\370\376\377f?ϻ\005v\233\246]\366\343\321\313=\223{M\313\300\350\023\314\354o\321\372\357\264y\376\373\347K\\\357XƟa\242\352\207\336wUi=\270\t\371\275i\365y\314\321\371q;2\221\341ʗ\352~\266\333\357\225I\372\376\001\222\231bH\231\371\017MӜ\302y\214HL9\371\004\006\305\314وL\261\f\353\233\351\334\353\071\020\241\310Hk\224\225\370\223\211\342p\242\063\315e\270T\002\305\310وJ\261\204\351\317\340y\353,2\251\336\371\227=\271\025\350\272\377"..., 

    a=0x34e6480 "8\310\324\065$B\362\236#1\373\344료\002\036%\374\367\023\305\004\060\213\247\305\021\254\325,\316\334$G\300\313\335G\342΅71T\025\352=\234uC9y_/Kx:\251\306\327cR1\302\060ȹ\316?\035\346>\227ި5E \217E\364C0\254\035\215{\370lX@\001\"\305\373\326\016\336\034ԋ93\361\252)\225\361;\177]q\216\277\346\273\300o\rK\232:\377oy\375\377\036\315O?\266\273\032\272Û-W\365\273o}q\r\257\022\331\324U\251˛\206\377\377qs\375\210\321\332\367-a\366\217*\201Sb\217Ǎ\006\036wp\037\223\231\250\364\037ue", this=<optimized out>, size=<optimized out>)

    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-object-recognition-0.4.8/debian/ros-electric-object-recognition/opt/ros/electric/stacks/object_recognition/object_recognition_core/build/source/ecto_opencv/include/opencv_candidate/hamming.h:32

32  /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-object-recognition-0.4.8/debian/ros-electric-object-recognition/opt/ros/electric/stacks/object_recognition/object_recognition_core/build/source/ecto_opencv/include/opencv_candidate/hamming.h: No such file or directory.

    in /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-object-recognition-0.4.8/debian/ros-electric-object-recognition/opt/ros/electric/stacks/object_recognition/object_recognition_core/build/source/ecto_opencv/include/opencv_candidate/hamming.h
```

I did have this working on another computer, but on the two that I have since tried, I have gotten this error. All three are with electric and Ubuntu 11.10. :-\

---

To answer both of the comments, I did:
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-object-recognition

Within the object recognition stack is ecto_opencv. In the orb_template.py and orb_track.py the files reference this source for everything opencv related, ie:
from ecto_opencv.calib import PoseDrawer, DepthValidDraw

I did compile Opencv on one computer and I received the same illegal instruction error.

Your help and ideas are much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36945/illegal-instruction-(object_recognition)/) by [cgomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2673/cgomez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-06-25**:
Can you try removing any special compile flags before compiling opencv? What kind of system do you use?

**Comment by [cgomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2673/cgomez/) on 2012-06-25**:
I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 - I used CMake 2.8.5. I just used whatever was already set after running cmake-gui. Which would be the special compile flags? (I followed instructions here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide, as far as the optional parameters).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-06-25**:
I was more thinking about the system hardware and architecture. If it is a "standard machine" it should work. I've never had to remove compile options, but things like SSE instructions might be good candidates.

**Comment by [cgomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2673/cgomez/) on 2012-06-26**:
How about this?
3.0.0-21-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 25 17:57:41 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux; and as far as a processor Intel Core 2 CPU 6700.

**Comment by [cgomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2673/cgomez/) on 2012-06-26**:
Also I tried this way: http://answers.ros.org/question/32015/running-ecto-object-recognition-on-ubuntu-1110-ros/
and after getting through the errors in rosmake, I got the same response. I could run the orb_template, but when I ran the orb_track, I get an illegal instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The opencv library is compiled for recent cpus. I had the same error and solved it by compiling OpenCV myself (with standard compiler flags).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0